# Unity- windowed fullscreen black borders

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, fullscreen

Hi I'm new to unity and playing around to get used to everything.

I have been doing some tests and so far everthing is going ok but I stumbled on something I could not find a descent solution for.

When building the game I have black borders on the side. how can I get rid of them so the game is really full screen?

I disabled the display resolutiong box and hard coded in that the window goes 'Windows fullscreen' but now I have these anoying black borders.

Can anybody push me in the right direction?

Thanks.

This is what i tried as code. but no success.

```
Debug.Log(Screen.currentResolution); // check if i find the native screen resolution. test passed
Screen.SetResolution(Screen.currentResolution.width, Screen.currentResolution.height, true); //getting black borders. set test failed
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your main camera setup like?

Could also be related to aspect ratio. If you're on a widescreen and it is set to 4:3 then you'll have black borders.

Comment: Well in the player all aspect ratio's are checked, so i guess everything is covered (also checked 'others') and the idea is to hard code it in. so the game detect the native screen resolution and the set the setting for the player (no relolution dialog on startup) I'm adding the code that i tried to the original post.

Comment: i think it has something to do with the viewport rect as i change those number the camera view changes (in the unity editor).but as soon as i build it it goes back. trying to find a way to code it in. still searching how to do this from a script. (i'm a beginner so its a lot of searching for me.)

Comment: Ok, see if this is relevant:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1244191/how-to-remove-black-bars-on-different-game-resolut.html

Also, this has a thorough explanation: http://www.aclockworkberry.com/managing-screen-resolution-and-aspect-ratio-in-unity-3d/

Comment: No that i already tried. i just tried the build on my gf's computer and there it works correctly. What strange is now that other unity builds(not from me so i can not see the source) are running correctly. now i'm looking in my video settings to see if i find a solution. (strange thing is its only my build. others work fine) thanks for the effort.

Comment: I just restarted an new project an now then borders are gone. I set each setting one by one to see what would trigger the borders. Strangly nothing did. So I ended up with an excact copy but with no borders. Thank you for your time.